# Should I list my MPS degree on my resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, education, qualification, masters

In May, I will have a Master of Professional Studies in Informatics with a concentration in web development. The college is an accredited state university. I'm currently unemployed and seeking work for immediate employment. Should I list this degree on my resume or will I be considered "over-qualified" for most web developer positions?

Comment: I don't think a degree by itself makes you overqualified for anything.

Comment: Any degree that's relevant to the position you are applying for should certainly be included. Resumes should be tailored to each job application.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I list this degree on my resume or will I be considered "over-qualified" for most web developer positions?

Depends on the specific jobs you are applying, and the requirements they may have. It is usually recommended that you tailor your application to better fit each candidate job position, so you have better chances of landing it.

Personally, we can't know *a priori* if some company X will find such degree as over-qualified. However, seems to me that if you plan to apply for jobs related to Web Development, **mentioning a degree with a concentration in that area will most likely be advantageous to your application**.

I'd say you include it (surely a good background check will reveal it anyways), but also try to keep your options open; don't rely on just one prospect company.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, list it.  As DarkCygnus noted, a background check will find out any information not on your resume/cv.

However, you will have to be prepared to discuss *why* you are interested in a particular position that you might be overqualified for.

A good company will hire the best available *even if technically "overqualified.*  When I had a say in hiring, if the best candidate had a combination of experience, skills and education greater than the position required we'd (often) bring them in at a higher level (and with a greater compensation).  This paid off in the long term as there was less of a learning curve - they were more productive and required less hand-holding than an inexperienced person.

You worked hard for that masters.  Use it to your advantage.